# Max. value of $f(u,v,w,x) = u^2+v^2+w^2+x^2-29u+v+w+x$

Tags: calculus

(1) If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2+xy = 1$. Then Minimum value of $f(x,y) = x^3y+xy^3$ is

(2) If $f(u,v,w,x) = u^2+v^2+w^2+x^2-29u+v+w+x+10$ and $u,w\in [-3,3]$ and $v,x\in [1,3]$

Then Max. value of $f(u,w,v,x)$ is

My Try:

(1) Let $x^2+y^2=1-xy$ put value of $x^2+y^2$ into $f(x,y) = xy(x^2+y^2)=xy(1-xy)=(xy)-(xy)^2$

So $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}-\left(xy-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\leq \frac{1}{4}$

How can i calculate Minimum of $f(xy)$

for $(II)$

$f(u,v,w,x)=\displaystyle \left(u-\frac{29}{2}\right)^2+\left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(w+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+10-(\frac{29}{2})^2-3(\frac{1}{2})^2$

Now How can i calculate after that Thanks

Now i have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't you mixed up "minimum" with "maximum" in at least one question?

Anyway, your solution of the first exercise is perfect, if you want to calculate the maximum; for the minimum, you easily see that $f(x,y)$ is unbounded from below, try plugging in big positive values of $x$ and $y$ (or observe that - as $x,y$ vary on $\mathbb{R}$ - also the "product variable" $z=xy$ does; but then $z(1-z)$ is a parabola and you know where it goes for $z\rightarrow \pm\infty).$

For the second one, the minimum value would be attained when all the squares are zero, but this can't be realized, due to the domain of the single variables. You can anyway set to zero the $w$ parenthesis and minimize the others (it may be useful to sketch a graph for the single terms). The same goes for the maximum: for the $w$ parenthesis, you see that its maximum value is reached for $w=3$ (in general, you have to get the biggest possible value of what is to square). [Oh, I don't know where does that $10$ come from, but it doesn't modify the argument...]